# Android serial communication via C program

Tags: android, c, communication

I searched on the net guide for serial communication from Android devices and C programs via USB port, but I didn't find nothing special. Does someone knows how can I implement this communication?

I'm not really searching a guide to project serial communication for Android, but to send or receive - via serial - data, permitting me to read or send from terminal.

**EDIT** I'm trying to search more, but I can't find nothing special.

I noticed that when I connect my Samsung Galaxy SII plus via usb, I found

> /dev/ttyACM0
>
> /dev/ttyACM1

That are probably linked with my phone (read an write stream?), because they aren't there when SII isn't connected. I downloaded a serial monitor app via Play Story and created this simple program to send some basic text to my phone:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int open_port(void);

int main(void) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Starting reading serial port... ");

    int port = open_port();

    fprintf(stderr, "%d... [DONE]\n", port);
    
    return 0;
}

int open_port(void) {
    int fd, n; /* File descriptor for the port */

    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
    } else {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    }

    n = write(fd, "ATZ", 3);

    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);
    }

    return (fd);
}
```

Nothing is failing when I write data, but my phone isn't receiving nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open serial port on Android from C code, because Android does not allow direct device access to regular apps.

So you have to use Java. Here are two Android libraries for adding support for USB-to-serial cables to your app:

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver

And here is an open-source app, which uses one of these libs:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ksksue.app.terminal&hl=en

But if you got root on your Android, you can use the same C code you're using on Linux to communicate over serial, you can even do `echo "data data" > /dev/ttyACM0` in the Android shell.

Comment: I'm using exactly your code but nothing is happen. I downloaded also your app but says "can not open". My device is rooted

Comment: Are you using USB-to-serial cable? Or just plugging your phone into PC using regular USB cable?

Comment: Regular USB cable. What's the difference? Serial cable use every 4 pin of USB?

Comment: The difference is that your Galaxy S2 is creating `/dev/ttyACM0` / `/dev/ttyACM1` to act like a USB modem and provide wireless internet to your PC. These are system devices, used internally by Android, you cannot use them for your own code (actually you can with root, but this will break radio drivers, until you reboot the phone). But if you plug something like this in your phone's USB port, you can control Arduino and other stuff with it: http://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Serial-Adapter-Chipset-CB-FTDI/dp/B006AA04K0

Comment: Thank you for helping me, finally I'm starting to understand. Exactly how can I do it with root? Can you share me a link how-to-do ? Or some tips also

Comment: Do `ls -l /dev/tty*` on your Android. One of these files will be the endpoint for `/dev/ttyACM0` on your PC. So you do `sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0` on your PC, then `for f in /dev/tty*; echo something > $f ; done` on your Android in the root shell.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, if Java can do it then c can do it. If c can't do something, there is no language that can.

Comment: Honestly I agree, but none provides me more infos about how to do it.